# In Bash, how can I modify a global variable in a function of a module?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a global variable in my script:

```
export _ERR
. library.sh #import my functions
```

In library.sh, 
I would like to set it in function A:

```
function_a () 
{
  [[ -f /mnt/file.txt ]] && {
    _ERR="Error file does not exist"
  }
}
```

And later in the main script call function A

```
output=$(functionA)
```

and display `$_ERR` if $ERR is not empty:

```
[[ -n _ERR ]] && echo ${_ERR}
```

But _ERR is always empty in my main script.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By capturing the output with command substitution, you run the function in a subshell. A subshell can't change variable values in the parent shell.

Comment: Hi choroba, output=$(..) created the subshell I didn't realize. If I call  functionA, _ERR gets affected the message in case of a problem. it works, thanks!